# Make a panel visible only if textbox validations are accepted asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, validation

I have a panel in asp.net which should become visible only if a particular textbox has input which is validated and accepted. In all other scenarios it should remain hidden.

The code for the textbox and its validations is:

```
<td class="auto-style4" align="left">
    ID:
    <br />
</td>
<td class="style10">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="txtbox" Height="25px" Width="200px" >
    </asp:TextBox>
</td>
<td >
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" style="display: block;"> 
        <asp:requiredfieldvalidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1"  ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="Please enter valid bug ID."  Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" runat="server" SetFocusOnError="true">*   </asp:requiredfieldvalidator>
        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ErrorMessage="Bug ID should be numeric." runat="server" Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationExpression="^\d+$">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" style="display: block;">
        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator4" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ErrorMessage="Bug ID should be numeric." runat="server" Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationExpression="^\d+$">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
    </asp:Panel>
</td>
```

I have written a function to check if it a number because I'm not sure whether validations can be directly checked in the code given below: (The panel to be made visible is Panel3)

```
Protected Sub RBL_EnterBugID_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles RBL_EnterBugID.SelectedIndexChanged
    If RBL_EnterBugID.SelectedItem.Text = "Yes" Then
        Panel1.Visible = True
        Panel2.Visible = False
        If IsInputNumeric(TextBox1.Text) Then
            Panel3.Visible = True
        Else
            Panel3.Visible = False
        End If

    Else
        Panel1.Visible = False
        Panel2.Visible = True
        Panel3.Visible = False
        Panel5.Visible = True
    End If
End Sub
```

I am new to asp.net and any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: did you faced any error while implementing this ?

Comment: No I am not facing any error; however the panel is never becoming visible

Comment: try putting a break point at `RBL_EnterBugID_SelectedIndexChanged` and see what is the result you are getting

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be hiding/displaying the PANEL3 object in the event code for `RBL_EnterBugID_SelectedIndexChanged`

What is `RBL_EnterBugID_SelectedIndexChanged`?  Is it a radiobutton?
Is the CASE correct? Because `YES` is not the same as `Yes` or `yes`

Maybe you can replace the if statement

```
If RBL_EnterBugID.SelectedItem.Text = "Yes" Then
```

with the if statement

```
If trim(lcase(RBL_EnterBugID.SelectedItem.Text)) = "yes" Then
```

Also you can take out this code

```
If IsInputNumeric(TextBox1.Text) Then
  Panel3.Visible = True
Else
  Panel3.Visible = False
End If
```

And replace it with

```
Panel3.Visible = IsInputNumeric(TextBox1.Text)
```